# Sublime Text 3 - подсветка php кода

Tags: php, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Проблема: При вставке php кода в html документ, php не подсвечивается. Прилагаю скрин. Если это файл только с php, то код нормально подсвечивается(2 скрин). Можно как-то сделать, чтобы и html и php в одном файле вместе имели подсветку, может плагин какой-то нужно установить?

Также есть еще проблемка с тем, что сублайм часто не понимает код, это также видно на 1 скрине красным цветом, хотя ошибок там нет и все исправно работает. Из-за этого появляются проблемы написания кода, когда он начинает 2 кавычки подставлять вместо одной закрывающей, вообще делает кавычки серыми и темными, что их вообще не видно становится и т.п. Можно как-то исправить это тоже? Заранее спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `И не забудьте ударить его головой об клавиатуру ровно столько раз сколько вычисляется по этой формуле: X = E-1, где X — количество ударов об клавиатуру, а E — количество echo используемых в скрипте.` Цитата

Comment: Почему бы вам не собрать все необходимые для постройки html данные **до** начала его вывода?

Comment: С выводом пост это лишь пример корректной подсветки php синтаксиса) Ваш ответ увидел, помогло- спасибо!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас файл определился как HTML - это можно увидеть в правом нижнем углу.

- Ctrl+Shift+P
- ss php    - Полная команда: «Set Syntax: PHP»
- Enter